# UnboundLocalError while running in else case in python

Tags: python

I wrote a function that looking for some strings in text file which defined as "keys",
In case that all the keys has found, the function will return True and will print ok.

If a specific key isn't found,  the function will append the checked key to a list.
If the condition won't be True [the else case] the function will return False, and will print the list that contain all the missing keys from file.

Currently, the True case is working fine, the else case [if one or more of the keys are missing] giving me the following error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name_key_flag' referenced before assignment [which I think causing due to indentation issue / or a global variable that out of the scope]

Thanks for the help, here is my code:

```
import datetime
import os.path
import logging

recipe_name = 'Sanity_CS.py'
NR_log = 'NR_' + str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[0] + '.log'
lst = []


def pre_conditions():
    with open(NR_log, 'r') as logfile:
        name_key = recipe_name
        app_key = 'Application was powered-up successfully, mode is: Review'
        api_key = 'API recipe was chosen'
        lot_key = 'Lot was created successfully'
        recipe_key = 'Recipe execution started'
        wafer_key = 'The Wafer was loaded successfully'
        recipe_pause_key = 'Recipe run is paused'
        program_key = 'Moving to Program mode'
        recipe_creation_key = 'Recipe was saved successfully under the name: sanity_2022-06-22_Ver_5.1'
        lst1 = lst
        for num, line in enumerate(logfile, 1):
            if name_key in line:
                name_key_flag = 1
            else:
                lst.append('\nError: Script was not successfully executed \n')

            if app_key in line:
                app_key_flag = 1
            else:
                lst.append('\nError: Application was failed to power up.\n')

            if api_key in line:
                api_key_flag = 1
            else:
                lst.append("\nError: Recipe type [API] was not successfully chosen\n")

            if lot_key in line:
                lot_key_flag = 1
            else:
                lst.append("\nError: A lot was not successfully created.\n")

            if recipe_key in line:
                recipe_key_flag = 1
            else:
                lst.append("\nError: A timeout, recipe was not executed\n")

            if wafer_key in line:
                wafer_key_flag = 1
            else:
                lst.append("\nError: The wafer was not loaded.\n")

            if recipe_pause_key in line:
                recipe_pause_key_flag = 1
            else:
                lst.append("\nError: The recipe was not paused.\n")

            if program_key in line:
                program_key_flag = 1
            else:
                lst.append("\nError: The script was not switch to program key.\n")

            if recipe_creation_key in line:
                recipe_creation_key_flag = 1
            else:
                lst.append("\nError: The recipe was not saved.\n")

        if (
                name_key_flag == 1 and app_key_flag == 1 and api_key_flag == 1 and lot_key_flag == 1 and recipe_key_flag == 1 and wafer_key_flag == 1 and recipe_pause_key_flag == 1 and program_key_flag == 1 and recipe_creation_key_flag == 1):
            return True, print("Pre conditions are OK.")

        return False, print("false")  # falsecase(lst1) - printing list function
```

Comment: Replace the big if with just `if not lst:`

Comment: The error can be solved by setting `name_key_flag = None` before your for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also suggest to clean up your code something like below. Since you do not use the flags anywhere else in your code (apparently), it would be sufficient just to check for the existence of the keys and then append.

```
def pre_conditions():
with open(NR_log, 'r') as logfile:
    name_key = recipe_name
    app_key = 'Application was powered-up successfully, mode is: Review'
    api_key = 'API recipe was chosen'
    lot_key = 'Lot was created successfully'
    recipe_key = 'Recipe execution started'
    wafer_key = 'The Wafer was loaded successfully'
    recipe_pause_key = 'Recipe run is paused'
    program_key = 'Moving to Program mode'
    recipe_creation_key = 'Recipe was saved successfully under the name: sanity_2022-06-22_Ver_5.1'
    lst1 = lst
    for num, line in enumerate(logfile, 1):
        if name_key not in line:
            lst.append('\nError: Script was not successfully executed \n')
        if app_key not in line:
            lst.append('\nError: Application was failed to power up.\n')
        if api_key not in line:
            lst.append("\nError: Recipe type [API] was not successfully chosen\n")
        if lot_key not in line:
            lst.append("\nError: A lot was not successfully created.\n")
        if recipe_key not in line:
            lst.append("\nError: A timeout, recipe was not executed\n")
        if wafer_key not in line:
            lst.append("\nError: The wafer was not loaded.\n")
        if recipe_pause_key not in line:
            lst.append("\nError: The recipe was not paused.\n")
        if program_key not in line:
            lst.append("\nError: The script was not switch to program key.\n")
        if recipe_creation_key not in line:
            lst.append("\nError: The recipe was not saved.\n")
    if not lst:
        return True, print("Pre conditions are OK.")
    return False, print("false")  # falsecase(lst1) - printing list function
```

Answer (score 3):

In the else case, you are using the `name_key_flag` without ever giving it a value, resulting in this error. To fix it, give it a value such as `name_key_flag = 0` before your for loop.